# How to deal with edge cases where fuzzy matching does not return a result?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-8.0

I have two tables in a MySQL database:

1. `address` that includes a `description` field which at most has a city name and a country buried somewhere inside it. There are also `latitude` and `longitude` fields
2. `city` that includes `name` and `latitude` and `longitude` (sourced from [geonames.org](http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/cities1000.zip))

For each record in `address` I need to assign the `city.id` of a matching record in `city`.

My current solution involves using Python to cycle through each unassigned record in `address` and query `city` for all records where `city.latitude` and `city.longitude` are close to `address.latitude` and `address.longitude`. I then use a fuzzy matching function to compare `address.description` with the `city.name` of each `city` record and add the `city.id` of the highest scoring `city` record to the `address` record.

This works fine for 99.9% of the records but there are always some exceptions where `address.description` is just too different to `city.name`. For example "Cologne" vs "Koln".

I could include a dictionary of alternative city names inside the Python code but this isn't a scalable solution. I'm thinking that I need to have some kind of option that if Python can't find a fuzzy match on `address.city_name` then I build in some functionality so I can manually identify the city name in `address.description` and then add this to a `city.alternative_name` field. I'll then adapt the Python code to search the `city.alternative_name` field if a match can't be found against `city.name` field. Geonames actually includes a alternative city names column in their data extract so I could load this in as some base data.

Is a `city.alternative_name` field the best approach to deal with unmatchable records? Worth me mentioning that I'm not looking for advice on alternative Python packages for matching city names, e.g. [geodict](https://github.com/petewarden/geodict/blob/master/populate_database.py) or [geotxt](https://pypi.org/project/geotext/). These have the same issue as my code - at some point they won't be able to find a match. I need to develop a solution for these edge cases.

I also need to think about the possibility of having multiple alternative city names and I could see things getting messy at that point. I guess I could create a `city_alternative_name` table where I could add multiple records with different `city_alternative_name.name` fields that were linked to the same `city` record...?

Comment: 99.9% -- That sounds great!

Comment: Maybe their "Premium Data" would be worth buying?  And they might even appreciate knowing of the "unmatchables" that you find.

Comment: The USPS has a program for turning any US address into a 9-digit zip; would that be worth acquiring for that one country?  Do other countries have such?

Comment: Do you also need Deutschland vs Germany vs West Germany vs Allemagne vs Niemcy?

Comment: Solution with a third table matching all alternatives seems a good option.
I imagine that you checked geonames.org to see if they don’t have a direct API endpoint that would answer your need?

Comment: Hi @RickJames. Thanks for the comments. This is really a personal project so 720 euro a year for the premium data is a bit over my budget. On USPS - I need data for all countries. On country names - I only need to cover off city names as I have the lat long coordinates that denote country.

Comment: @Floh - unfortunately they don't provide an API. Even if they did I fear they'd charge quite a bit for it!

Comment: @Jossy - See if https://www.maxmind.com/en/worldcities is still around.  No code, but a diff dataset.

Comment: I don't understand the part when you said "there are always some exceptions where address.description is just too different to city.name. For example "Cologne" vs "Koln".". Did you mean they extract text that is not a city name as a name or correctly detect the city part but refer to a wrong city?

Comment: Hi @EsraaAbdelmaksoud - I mean that the fuzzy matching function I've built doesn't return any results because "Cologne" and "Koln" are too different for it to be able to detect that the strings are the same city

Comment: He can still use FuzzyWuzzy to get it matched with the city name and then change it easily.

Comment: @RickJames - thanks for the heads up on maxmind. That link is dead but had a look through the site. They seem to be focused on IP based locationing and I couldn't see an option to use lat/long coordinates

Comment: @Jossy - Sorry; I should have checked that old link before posting it.  Search around some more; there could be others.

Answer (score 1):

Your 99.9% is absolutely great! Since you wrote that when it fails it retrieves nothing, you may use a different fuzzy approach for this part. The idea of looking for alternative city names in a table is good, but it would fail if there's a typo in the city name.

You can use FuzzyWuzzy to do this. Pass to it a json dictionary or even a list of exceptional city names that are not available in geodict. Then, use your preferred ratio type. This will help you to extract the city and get the matching score to decide if you need further processing. Here's an example for the code you can use:

```
choices = ["Atlanta", "New York", "Florida", "Dallas"]

process.extractOne(" Villa 90, Soho Square, Florida, USA.", choices, scorer=fuzz.partial_ratio)
```

The result will be `("Florida", 100)`

Comment: Thanks Esraa but as I mentioned I don't need fuzzy matching solutions - I'm pretty happy with the 99.9% I've got from the function I have. I'm looking for a solution that handles edge cases where fuzzy matching doesn't stand a chance, e.g. Koln vs Cologne.

Comment: This is to be used only when your method fails. If you use a look up table, it would fail if you have any spelling differeces such as missing the umlaut.